# create Advanced and Custom Dynamics CRM online report

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, fetchxml

I know how to create the report using ADVANCED FIND but I want to create a Custom Report in CRM online using fetchxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: [This post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10234.microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-develop-fetch-xml-based-ssrs-reports-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx) will teach you many things like Getting FetchXML from Advanced Find query & customize it, build a report from scratch, design it, etc.

Try to learn Some SQL stuffs & CRM videos which will help you.

For SQL to fetchxml query converter use: http://www.sql2fetchxml.com/

Comment: so first step is to learn SQL and create query later convert it into FetchXML. Right? Either SQL or Fetch XML any one of this is enough no?

Comment: yes, SQL is always a mandate for Developer.. SQL is good for on-premise, whereas Fetchxml is mandatory for CRMonline reports (as SQL server is inaccessible)

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that, im using ONLINE, not on-premises          
      and i dont know Fetch XML, is it okay to write whole query in sql and convert it into the FetchXML.?

Comment: upto you, like Jonas mentioned in another answer - you can build fetchxml also using tool..

Answer (score 3):

A good way to get up and running with FetchXML is to use the FetchXML Builder tool in XrmToolBox.

XrmToolBox can be downloaded from [www.xrmtoolbox.com](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com) and the FetchXML Builder is installed from the Plugins Store inside XrmToolBox.

More information on FetchXML Builder can be found on [fxb.xrmtoolbox.com](http://fxb.xrmtoolbox.com) and a tutorial on how to create advanced views with it in [this article on MSDynamicsWorld.com](https://msdynamicsworld.com/story/create-advanced-views-microsoft-dynamics-crm-using-fetchxml-builder).